# Terminating an application on critical error during Spring initialization?

Tags: java, spring

If I encounter a critical error during initialization of my Spring application context, what's the recommended approach for aborting and shutting down the application?  My application is not a web app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, your application should always exit gracefully.

You can call `System.exit(0)` but this is not graceful.

If your program cannot find or parse the application context, the code should exit gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a good practice, but I usually catch the exception, log it, output to the user and let the application finish by itself.

roughly:

```
main(String[]  args) {
   try {
       loadApp();
       while(running) { blah }
   }
   catch(LoadException e) {
       log(e);
       output(e);
   }
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, the user should be given a "user friendly" error.  As most users for instance if they received something like "NULL POINTER EXCEPTION", would not really understand what it meant.  Where as if the exception had been parsed and presented to the user with "Unable to find configuration file", this would generally be more appropriate.  Of course log the stack trace details though :)

Comment: As I said, this is  roughly what I would do, then the `output(e)` can apply something to show a meaningful error. I don not mean to be precise, just gave my 2cents in a reduced version to make my point